# Haartraining opencv

Tags: opencv

I am tryng to train cascades using haar training.I have used the following parameters.

```
C:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin>opencv_haartraining -data haar -vec train.vec  -bg neg.
txt -numPos 1000 -numNeg 2000 -nstages 10 -mem 2000 -mode all -w 30 -h 32
```

but i am getting the following error

```
Data dir name: haar
Vec file name: train.vec
BG  file name: neg.txt, is a vecfile: no
Num pos: 2000
Num neg: 2000
Num stages: 10
Num splits: 1 (stump as weak classifier)
Mem: 2000 MB
Symmetric: TRUE
Min hit rate: 0.995000
Max false alarm rate: 0.500000
Weight trimming: 0.950000
Equal weights: FALSE
Mode: BASIC
Width: 30
Height: 32
Applied boosting algorithm: GAB
Error (valid only for Discrete and Real AdaBoost): misclass
Max number of splits in tree cascade: 0
Min number of positive samples per cluster: 500
Required leaf false alarm rate: 0.000976563

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+
|  0|
+---+


Number of features used : 234720

Parent node: NULL

*** 1 cluster ***
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Vec file sample size mismatch) in icvGetHaarTra
iningDataFromVec, file C:\Downloads\Software\OpenCV-2.2.0-win\OpenCV-2.2.0\modul
es\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1929
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:\Downloads\Software\OpenCV-2.2.0-win\OpenCV-2.2.0\modules\haartrain
ing\cvhaartraining.cpp:1929: error: (-2) Vec file sample size mismatch in functi
on icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromVec


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin>cmd |as.txt
'as.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i am using a vec file having 1000 samples which i downloaded from the internet,and have 2000 negative samples.

Comment: "i am using a vec file having 1000 samples which i downloaded from the internet"   any chance, the thing is corrupted ? ( like e.g. a txt/binary truncation )

Comment: when i tried to view it with opencv_createsampe it was working...

Answer (score 0):

"Vec file sample size mismatch" - Try checking the site for the size of the samples. The vec file may not be the one for 30x32 images(which you are trying to pass as -w 30 -h 32).

This is just a guess. Try it. And try using traincascade object. It is there in $OpencvDir$/apps/traincascade/. Compile it like any other object. It can be used for LBP and HOG as well.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Prasanna S

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of w and h is different from the setting in info.txt. You should modify w's and h's of all images in info.txt int 30:32.